# Typescript : is there a way to distinguish classes with same structures?

Tags: class, typescript, properties, collision

For sure this kind of stuff could be implemented in some other way but I'm still curious why TS doesn't warn. Same structures could have different data.

```
class ComponentContainer<TComponent> extends Array<TComponent> {}

class Context<TComponent> extends Array<ComponentContainer<TComponent>> {}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Component<T> { constructor(public value: T) {} }

class Movable extends Component<boolean> {
  constructor(value: boolean = true) { super(value) }
}

class Static extends Component<boolean> {
  constructor(value: boolean = true) { super(value) }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const ctx: Context<Movable> = new Context()

ctx[0].push(new Static()) // <-- No error
```

**EDIT**
Could be a beginning of an alternative here :https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types don't presume that value should be an instance of specified class. `Movable` class is used as interface here:

```
const ctx: Context<Movable> = new Context()
```

If a value should be an instance of `Movable` class, this check is usually performed at run time with `if (value instanceof Movable)`. It will be tricky to implement in `Array` subclass, it may be better for `Context` to implement its own API that allows to validate values instead of extending `Array`.

> Same structures could have different data

But they don't have different data. `Static` conforms to `Movable` *interface*, so it doesn't cause type error. Similarly, this will work, because the object conforms to this interface:

```
ctx[0].push({ value: true })
```

And will cause TypeScript type error if it doesn't:

```
ctx[0].push({ value: 1 })
```

It's possible to additionally enforce the value to be an instance of `Movable` through type checks with merged interface:

```
interface Movable {
    constructor: typeof Movable
}
class Movable extends Component<boolean> {
  constructor(value: boolean = true) { super(value) }
}
```

It still will be possible to cheat typing system with:

```
ctx[0].push({ constructor: Movable, value: 1 });
```

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation ! I though about the idea of using instanceof in the run time as the solution. I expected to avoid that kind of process in the same manner that I can now with "typeof foo === bar"

Comment: You're welcome. Usually you don't need `instanceof` validation, unless there are `instanceof` checks in other places that will result in runtime errors because an object isn't an instance of a class. Context<Movable> guarantees that provided value matches the interface, and most times it's enough.

Comment: Enough until stuff happens during the instanciation the interfaces matches but the logic inside their respective constructor may differs ! Have a nice week !

Comment: But constructor logic is irrelevant here, because the constructor is executed before you call `ctx[0].push`, it serves to result in an object with specific interface. In your case it assigns `value` property which is a part of public interface and can be type-checked. That's why the concept of interfaces exists in OOP. Once there's an object that matches the interface, it doesn't matter where it originates from.

Comment: Private fields are a good way to ensure incompatibility between types, two classes even with the same private fields are incompatible by definition: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20x%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20x%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20varA%3A%20A%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be irrelevant, what I would say is that arguments can be transformed before assigned to the value property. 
Btw Titian, thanks for this info ! good to know

Comment: @Tiramitsu If they are transformed in a way the object becomes incompatible with expected type (e.g. you assign a number to boolean `value` property in constructor), there will be type error. If you encountered such problem, consider asking a question, there's a good chance there's a conventional solution.

Comment: I didn't think about necessarily change the type, 2 vectors class for example can handle their coordinates in different way. But that's more a design question right now.

Answer (score 1):

After playing a bit with your code in [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html), it seems like TypeScript is smart enough to detect that `Movable` and `Static` are basically the same type besides their name. They are both a `Component<boolean>` and have no properties, so it allows you to push a new `Static` instance into a `Movable` array. Only when I added a property to `Movable` which didn't exist in `Static` then TypeScript compiler showed an error, for example: [image]

I guess that's just how TypeScript works. It doesn't necessarily prohibit you from using different types on a generic object unless the type that's given is missing properties which exist on the expected type. That's why the following also works: [image]

Comment: Thank you ! I though until now typescript worked by matching the right semantic references ! Time to get that handbook :)